# Odin (Elementary OS 6) System Settings > About missing?

Tags: release-odin

After installing EOS 6 (Odin), there is no longer an 'About' panel in the Systems Settings. Is this omitted deliberately? Or am I missing some step to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look in the About plug issues:
https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-about/issues/219

> This page is now called "System"